# python beautifulsoup href prints as #

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

when I try to pull a particular href for a .zip file, all that is returned is #

I have stripped my script down so only the tricky part is left.  When I run the script with the test html ( which is a copy of target site ) without using my opener.open it works fine.  When I run it on the actual site,  I only receive #.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
#!usr/bin/env python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

class Opener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"

opener = Opener()

test = '<a id="dlbutton" href="https://www55.zippyshare.com/d/H7prSkjz/2176/Barrier%20Line%20Riddim%20-%20%20J.%20Small%20Records.zip"><div class="download"></div></a>'

dstar = 'https://www55.zippyshare.com/v/H7prSkjz/file.html'

def grabzip(url):
    link = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(url), "html.parser")
    for ziplink in link.find_all('a', id="dlbutton"):
       print(ziplink.get('href'))

grabzip(dstar)
```

Comment: Looks like the link is injected via Javascript. How did you make your local test copy?

Comment: By hand, out of luakit inspect element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Selenium/[Chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/) to navigate the site dynamically and grab the href:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www55.zippyshare.com/v/H7prSkjz/file.html")

print(driver.find_element_by_id("dlbutton").get_attribute("href"))
```

#### Output

```
https://www55.zippyshare.com/d/H7prSkjz/16761/Barrier%20Line%20Riddim%20-%20%20J.%20Small%20Records.zip
```